# Sorting a Laravel Collection by Many to Many Pivot Table Column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking at displaying a list of `asset`s belonging to a `product` in an order defined by `order_column` on the pivot table `product_asset`.  In this case, the [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby) function has no effect.  No errors are thrown, but it returns the collection array in the same order no matter what.

Here's what I have laid out currently:

**Database:**

```
    Schema::create('product_asset', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('asset_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('asset_id')->references('id')->on('assets')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('order_column')->nullable();
    });
```

**Model:**

```
/**
 * The assets that belong to the product.
 */
public function assets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset', 'product_asset')->withPivot('order_column');
}
```

**View:**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($resources->sortBy('pivot_order_column') as $resource)
        <li><a href="{{ $resource->url }}">{{ $resource->name }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I would be very appreciative of any help on this one!  Thanks in advance.

**Similar Issues:**

https://laravel.io/forum/04-17-2014-order-by-pivot-table-attribute-in-eloquent

[Laravel eloquent sorting by pivot in many to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500207/laravel-eloquent-sorting-by-pivot-in-many-to-many-relationships)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order the query using Indra's suggestion:

```php
public function assets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset', 'product_asset')->withPivot('order_column')
        ->orderBy('product_asset.order_column');
}
```

Or sort the result in Laravel:

```php
$resources->sortBy('pivot.order_column')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here `pivot_order_column` You dont have a column name `pivot_order_column` you have a column named `order_column`
You can access that on the relationship because you have correctly used `withPivot` on the relationship.