# How to order by many-to-many relationship Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have many-to-many relationship users|pivot|task
I need to order records by pivot table column(role) and by user table column(name). Ordering by pivot works, but order by users doesnt. Please give any advice how to fix this

Job model

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_job')
            ->using(UserJob::class)
            ->withPivot('role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

User Model

```
 public function jobs(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class,'user_job')
            ->using(UserJob::class)
            ->withPivot('role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Repository

```
return User::find($dto->getUserId())
            ->jobs()
            ->where($dto->getFilters())
            ->with('users')
            ->orderBy($dto->getSortBy(),$dto->getSortType()) // need to order by users.name
            ->paginate($dto->getPerPage());
```

Comment: Please see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299945/how-to-sort-by-a-field-of-the-pivot-table-of-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-eloq

Comment: @kewlashu example shows how to order by pivot table, and I need to order by users table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a Laravel Collection by Many to Many Pivot Table Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928725/sorting-a-laravel-collection-by-many-to-many-pivot-table-column)